# Deserialize JPA obect to JSON with relations

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this objects with relations:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model")
public class DataModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataModel", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<OutputField> outputFields;
}
```

and:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model_output_field")
public class OutputField {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "output_field_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "sourceTable")
    private String sourceTable;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "model_id")
    private DataModel dataModel;
}
```

and I want deserialize this json to Java object:

```
{
  "name": "New data model with join",
  "outputFields": [
    {
      "sourceTable": "r"
    },
    {
      "sourceTable": "ri"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try deserialize it using Jackson, I get it:
[image]
How can I put a parent reference in a child element using Jackson?

Comment: you use `@JsonIgnore` in datamodel

Comment: This does not affect this in any way and is not relevant to the issue at hand. This is done to avoid stack overflow

Comment: you get null for ignoring this....to mange circular reference u need to use JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference.....

Comment: Tnx. Work for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I used `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` annotations:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model")
public class DataModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference(value = "outputFields")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataModel", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<OutputField> outputFields;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model_output_field")
public class OutputField {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "output_field_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "sourceTable")
    private String sourceTable;

    @JsonBackReference(value = "outputFields")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "model_id")
    private DataModel dataModel;
}
```